# Is the Nazi-Asgardian connection in the Captain America movie new, or does it have a precedent somewhere?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, captain-america

In *Captain America: The First Avenger*, Red Skull powers most of his tech with the Tesseract, which is all but stated to be a piece of Asgardian tech left behind in one of the Earth visits referred to in *Thor*.

Since the real-world Nazis actually did have a penchant for Norse mysticism, it seems natural for the Nazi portion of Captain America's rogues gallery to have some connection like this to the *Thor* canon. **Is this movie the first time that connection has been made, or was it also made in the comics or earlier adaptations?**

Answer (score 10):

**The Red Skull and the [Cosmic Cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Cube) have quite a checkered history. But the comics do not play up the relationship as part of the Nazi obsession with Norse mythology. It is more the Skull's quest for personal aggrandizement and the ultimate victory of the Nazi agenda.**

- The Cosmic Cube and the Marvel Cinematic Universe's [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Cube#Film) are a bit different in their powers and origins. The Tesseract has been substituted for the Cosmic Cube to bring the Asgardian and Human worlds into conflict. This ensures greater integrity on the part of the cinematic universe characters.
- On the Marvel Earth #616, the Cosmic Cube gave its wielder power to manipulate reality directly. In the Cinematic Universe, the Tesseract was a power source being manipulated for a variety of different technologies.

[image: The Red Skull wielding the Cosmic Cube: Tales of Suspense #80 (Aug. 1966). Cover art by Jack Kirby and Don Heck.]

*The Red Skull wielding the Cosmic Cube: Tales of Suspense #80 (Aug. 1966). Cover art by Jack Kirby and Don Heck.*

Comment: What a fantastic answer. I was just reading the Tales of Suspense the other day in a newer version. It was where Red Skull managed to turn Captain America on his side. Can't quite remember how he managed to escape, but was a brilliant comic